# How to delete a node from a xml c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have a xml structure like this:-

```
<Person id="1" Name="Rahul lamba" Manager_Id="13" Department="IT" />
<Person id="6" Name="Saurabh" Manager_Id="4" Department="IT" />
<Person id="5" Name="Amitesh" Manager_Id="6" Department="IT" />
```

Now I want to delete **Manager_Id** node from XML from every line.

I tried this but nothing works out

```
XmlNodeList l = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Person");

 foreach (XmlNode item in l)
     {
         foreach (var  item1 in item.ChildNodes)
             {
                 if (item1 == "Manager_Id")
                     {
                        //Code to remove Manager_Id node.
                     }
             }
      }
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried where it says `//Code to ...`?

Comment: i haven't tried anything here because I am not getting anything first at **ChildNodes**.

Comment: Name, Manager_Id, Department aren't Nodes. That is attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily with Linq To Xml,

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //XDocument.Load(filename)

xDoc.Descendants("Person")
    .Select(x => x.Attribute("Manager_Id"))
    .Where(x => x!=null)
    .ToList().ForEach(a => a.Remove());

var newxml = xDoc.ToString(); //xDoc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: Getting exception **Object reference not set to an instance** at 2nd line of your code.

Comment: @Rahul your xml is mssing a **root** node. So  I added a root node while testing above code. Also, do all your Person nodes have a `Manager_Id` attribute?

Comment: @Rahul In case of some Person's doesn't have `Manager_Id ` attribute, I added `.Where(x => x!=null)`

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\MyXml.xml");
        reader.Read();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Persons/Person[@Manager_Id=6]");
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        reader.Close();
        doc.Save(@"D:\MyXml.xml");
```

removing all nodes with att

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\MyXml.xml");
        reader.Read();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        XmlNodeList lstNode = doc.SelectNodes("/Persons/Person[@Manager_Id]");
        foreach (XmlNode node in lstNode)
        {
            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        }
        reader.Close();
        doc.Save(@"C:\MyXml.xml");
```